# Is there a command to install a dmg

Tags: install, command-line, dmg

I want to install a dmg file on a remote server. All I have is an ssh access.
Since a DMG is a disk image, I tried to mount it, but mount does not seem to recognize its format.

`file` says my dmg file is a `VAX COFF executable`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

First, mount the dmg image : `hdiutil attach <image>.dmg`

The image will be mounted to `/Volumes/<image>`. Mine contained a package which i installed with: `sudo installer -package /Volumes/<image>/<image>.pkg -target /`

Finally unmount the image: `hdiutil detach /Volumes/<image>`.

Comment: I did that with `Docker.dmg` and I had no `<image>.pkg` so that dit not work

Comment: mine is `<image>.app` instead of `<image>.pkg` after doing `sudo hdiutil attach <image>.dmg`, how can i do then?

Comment: @jack If there is an .app within a DMG you usally can just drag/copy it to /Applications.

Comment: Sometimes application inside dmg is distributed as app folder. In such case you need to copy it as in this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308510/452756

Comment: It's amazing how complex it is to perform such a basic operation on a macOS CLI. Looks like they forgot about the "Think" in "Think Different".

Answer (score 23):

You should be able to mount the `.dmg` using:

```
hdiutil attach /path/to/file.dmg
```

And then copy its contents (which appears in `/Volumes`) where ever you like.

Answer (score 19):

I had to mount and copy the `.app` to `/Applications` folder.
For Etcher.app:

First as @trojanfoe said :

```
sudo hdiutil attach /Users/janatac/Etcher-1.2.1.dmg
```

Then

```
sudo cp -R /Volumes/Etcher\ 1.2.1/Etcher.app /Applications
```

You then have your application in `/Applications` folder

Don't forget to unmount the volume :

```
sudo hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Etcher\ 1.2.1/
```

Got it working after reading [instructions from a blog post](http://commandlinemac.blogspot.fr/2008/12/installing-dmg-application-from-command.html).

Answer (score 14):

If you want to script the install it requires a few more steps since the name of the `.dmg` file, the name of the Volume created, the name of the application, and the name of the device that needs to be detached can all be different. Plus they can have spaces in them.

Also a `.dmg` can have an `.app` file or a `.pkg` file in it and these require different behavior.

Here's a bash function to install a dmg from a remote URL:

```
# usage: installdmg https://example.com/path/to/pkg.dmg
function installdmg {
    set -x
    tempd=$(mktemp -d)
    curl $1 > $tempd/pkg.dmg
    listing=$(sudo hdiutil attach $tempd/pkg.dmg | grep Volumes)
    volume=$(echo "$listing" | cut -f 3)
    if [ -e "$volume"/*.app ]; then
      sudo cp -rf "$volume"/*.app /Applications
    elif [ -e "$volume"/*.pkg ]; then
      package=$(ls -1 "$volume" | grep .pkg | head -1)
      sudo installer -pkg "$volume"/"$package" -target /
    fi
    sudo hdiutil detach "$(echo "$listing" | cut -f 1)"
    rm -rf $tempd
    set +x
}
```

Note if your `.dmg` has an `.app` file that runs to install the program, then you will need to do something different again.

Comment: This will only work for dmg‘s containing ready-to-run apps, not for packages or installer apps.

Comment: @patrix can you give me some examples of packages and installer apps that I can test against to refine the answer?

Comment: Packages are easy (end in .pkg), but an installer app looks the same as a real one

Comment: this does not detach the file. `hdiutil: detach failed - No such file or directory`

Comment: fixes it: `sudo hdiutil unmount "$volume"/*.app`

Comment: i wish there was a way to do this without `sudo`

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza

I wish Apple would make this easier by providing and enforcing a single easy to use standard and giving developers tools to automatically convert their existing installers to use the new standard.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the command `open disk://host.tld/image.dmg`.

Comment: `open` didn't do anything, just exit, without error message.

Comment: Yes it does. I just tested it. It won't display anything until the disk image has been completely mounted, so you will have to wait a minute or so before it appears in /Volumes. (It works if you ssh in and type `open path/to/file.dmg`. I don't think `disk://host.tld/` works though.)

Comment: Helpful, though maybe not exactly what the OP needed. Thanks.

Comment: I found that `open -W </path/todmg>` worked (it waits until the volume has actually appeared).

Answer (score 0):

After you've downloaded the.dmg file. By pressing the right button, the file must be mounted and opened with the same picture.DiskImageMounter(Default).

[image] .

The. app file will then be shown. When the. app file appears, open the terminal and navigate to the write directory where the file is located. and type open -a/ExistingFileName.app in the command prompt, then press enter. This is how I use the macOS terminal to launch the.dmg file.

Comment: You can also just double-click the DMG file to open it. Also please be more specific about what you mean with "open the terminal go to the directory write open -a/FileName.app and hit enter", this seems to lack some details.

Comment: The OP only has "an ssh access", so he cannot open the `.dmg` this way.