# Using terminal, how can I install a DMG file without sudo rights?

Tags: terminal, install, dmg, sudo

All of the answers to this question [Is there a command to install a dmg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73926/is-there-a-command-to-install-a-dmg) work for me in installing a DMG file from the command line.

But I don't want to have users need to enter the `sudo` password, it is inconvenient.

How can I extract a DMG file to a executable directory without `sudo`? Or is there no way to do that?

Comment: If the software you wish to install is available via Homebrew Cask, you can install it from DMG without using `sudo`. You can [search](https://caskroom.github.io/search) the Homebrew Cask database.

Comment: Doesn't the [second answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/73929/37797) to the linked question work for you? That does not require sudo. A DMG by itself is not an installer, is it a problem of the software or installer within the DMG that is requiring sudo?

Comment: Yeah it probably will. i just assumed that needed `sudo` ... i will try it thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DMG is a disk image, not an installer. You can't see from the outside how a piece of software is installed just by it being distributed as a DMG.

That said, if the DMG contains an .app, your user might be able to "install" (copy) it to their `~/Applications/` folder. The software will be only available to this specific user.