# Is there a script/cmd that I can create/run that will allow me to install .dmg?

Tags: applescript, command-line, bash, python, package-management

I have been working on a "Mac Rollout Project". After I run the Macs through the Apple setup, I have a list of .DMG / Applications that I have to install. There is no particular order that the .DMG / Applications need to follow while being installed. It's just tedious.

**Is there a way that I create a script/pkg/sudo on the Mac, That will allow me to automate this process?**

(I have all of the applications that I need on an external hard drive)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73926/is-there-a-command-to-install-a-dmg

Comment: when you say install a dmg file do you mean what happens when you double click the dmg?

Comment: Hey jmh, How are you? Yes. I mean "what happens when you double click the dmg" Thank you so much for looking into this

Comment: Opening (mounting) a `.dmg` image is easy enough with AppleScript. You can even obtain its contents, such as an `.app` file.  However, that's where automation ends: you can't readily automate moving the `.app` file into `/Applications` due to macOS's quarantining.  I believe you can turn of these security features, but I'm not sure how wise that would be.